# Textarea scrollbar Firefox bug

Tags: html, css, textarea, scrollbar, overflow

I have some editable field. I use textarea to edit it and change source by jQuery. So i have some problem with area scrollbar. When I turn the scroll bars of (`overflow: hidden;`) component behaves just as if they were still inside and dumps the text to the next line. Is there any possible to remove it totally?

This is how it looks like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

For example this is view from Chrome:

[image]

[image]

Thx for help!

Comment: can we see what you already have done probably on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: This is typical behavior, it will not change anything if I will paste the JS, CSS and HTML, if it is a way checking the code here will not change anything

Comment: This is a typical behavior, we understand. but we have certain fireqalls that block the images and we cannot see any of those images you specified. So if you can show us some code we may be able to help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QnYNT/ OK look right here, Pictures do not have anything in common, they are a separate entity, et going on in the variable text box

Comment: But there is a difference; the two textareas in the fiddle are not the same. If you increase the width (in my case to `24ch`, but this may depend on the font), the right one fits the first two words on the same line, while the left one with the scrollbar doesn't have enough room and puts the second word on the next line. [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QnYNT/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QnYNT/3/).

Is this what you need. have scrollbars only when required

```
overflow: auto;
```